# run batch file at startup on windows start

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012, taskscheduler

Every morning when i restart Azure VM then i want to run batch file automatically.

This batch file is starting selenium grid. So what i did is added Task scheduler and created trigger to start script at Startup.

Then i tried to run the task manually but it doesnt do anything.

Although it may not be mandatory to paste code for batch file but still here it is

```
cmd /C start/MIN java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -port 4445
cmd /C start/MIN java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4445/grid/register
```

I have windows server 2012. When i manually click batch file then it run but not working via startup script

Answer (score 0):

You can add the batch file to system registry

to execute if any user log in: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]`

to execute if only current user log in: `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]`

or

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
```